# Get the real IP address of client with Rails and Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, networking, nginx, ip-address

My server doesn't have a public IP address, so I don't know how to get the real client's IP address.

This is my nginx's configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://domain1;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP     $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

In my Rails app's controller both `request.ip` and `request.remote_ip` return my server's gateway address.

How can i get the real IP of client?

How to get X-Forwarded-For value from Rails request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get the header value X-forwarded-for

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: It may not be the "REAL" ip of client if he is sitting behind proxy :) and you know :)

Comment: @Rizwan Sharif then we simply consider the proxy is the client. ^^

Comment: but the IP in my rails's log is gate_way address also.

Comment: I am no Rails guru but in PHP i can get x-forwarded-for like this  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

Comment: Your gateway might be doing Source Nat.  Where is nginx installed ? Behind gateway or on the same machine as gateway or same machine as apache ?

Comment: This is a potential security issue depending on yor proxy setup, as Rizwan mentioned, since it allows IP addresses to be spoofed pretty easily.  Checkout http://blog.gingerlime.com/2012/rails-ip-spoofing-vulnerabilities-and-protection/

Comment: I don't understand. Does the question not show that he is trying to get the X-Forwarded-For header value but the answer states that he should do it. Is the attempt in the question wrong?

Answer (score 21):

Rails was supposed to be doing it automatically for us, but it seems to be broken with current 3.x

I'm using this:

```
def ip() request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] || request.remote_ip end
```

Comment: How do I detect request from localhost? Before nginx I used to get 127.0.0.1, but now I get the private IP address instead...

Comment: A reminder that the header is not necessarily an IP but more specifically a list of IPs separated by commas, the left most being the original client.  If there's only one IP, the above code will work but I suspect not if there were more than one.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For.